# How can I give a unique dynamic value as a variable in the path of a jmeter post request using CSV file

Tags: csv, url, jmeter

The URL is below:

`{{cos_base_url}}/charger/chargerByQr/AzLMOD`

Here the last part of the URL needs to be unique for every hit. How can I do it?

If I set the random string function and replace it on the URL. How can I define the CSV data header on the function. The CSV should include only the QR code value.